# Mysql query to add a table and insert table data from another table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table (nightly routine) and then insert table data from another table.  Right now I get that the table already exists.  Not sure the syntax I should be using here.

[Err] 1050 - Table 'testgiver.safewp_users' already exists

```
DROP TABLE
IF EXISTS testgiver.safewp_users;
CREATE TABLE `testgiver.safewp_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_login` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_pass` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `user_nicename` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2014-01-01 10:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `display_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO safewp_users (`user_login`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `display_name`)
    SELECT
    ldap_full.uid,
    ldap_full.sn,
    ldap_full.mail,
    ldap_full.cn
FROM
    ldap_full
```

Comment: You want to recreate that table every day or you want to update it every day ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos - just update it.

Comment: @blankip Not sure what the problem is here. I think you need to provide a bit more information. Did you try executing the code you provided? If your above syntax is not working then please specify what error you are getting.

Comment: @Sid - I said that I get an error that table already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a simple typo.

```
CREATE TABLE `testgiver.safewp_users`
```

should probably read

```
CREATE TABLE `testgiver`.`safewp_users`
```

Otherwise, you are attempting to create a table called `'testgiver.safewp_users'` every single time.

Comment: Thank you.  It was driving me nuts.  And FYI - I always use the first syntax throughout my DB... and never have issues.  This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the quotes in your create table statement.  The quotes are causing you to attempt to create a table named testgiver.safewp_users in the default schema, instead of a table named safewp_users in the testgiver schema.